# Onclick activated by onmousedown

Tags: php, javascript, html, var

Is there a way to activate an onclick event like

```
onClick="variable();size()"
```

Where there is also a onmousedown event?

```
class="div_1" onClick="variable();size()" onmousedown="clickin(this)"
```

Where the onmousedown javascript will activate the onclick javascript?

```
function clickin(control) {
    var allElements = document.getElementById(control.id);
    for (var i=0; i<allElements.length; i++) { 
        eval(document.getElementById('elementId').getAttribute('onclick'));
    }
}
```

Comment: <input onClick="variable();size()" onmousedown="$(this).click()" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onclick` property usually gets turned into a function. So this will work:

```
<a onclick="alert('click');" onmousedown="this.onclick()">Click here to click</a>
```

**/Edit:**

```
<a id="a_target">Click here to click</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var a_target = document.getElementById('a_target');

     a_target.onclick = function(){ alert('click'); };   // CODE TO ADD ONCLICK
     a_target.onmousedown = function(){ this.onclick();  } // CODE TO ADD MOUSEDOWN

     // TO REMOVE THEM DO THIS
     a_target.onclick = a_target.onmousedown = function(){} // NO MORE CLICKS
     a_target.onmousedown = function(){
          alert('mousedown!'); // DISPLAYS POPUP
          a_target.onmousedown = function(){} // STOPS FROM CLICK
          a_target.onclick = function(){ alert('CLICK :D'); } // WILL POPUP CLICK NOW AND ON NEXT CLICK
     }

     // TO POPUP CLICK ONLY ON NEXT CLICK CHANGE ONMOUSEDOWN TO ONMOUSEUP
</script>
```

Comment: Is there way to do this outside the element? Like in the <script> after the onmousedown has been called?

Comment: Added more examples. Good luck buddy!